# How do I set up a raid configuration in a separate case from my computer?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata

I want to set up a RAID 5 configuration with a bunch of drives but my current case has no hot swap bays and doesn't have enough bays or sata ports to connect them all in the same case.  I want to put the drives into their own case with hot swap cages and connect them using something like a SAS expander or a sata backplane and then connect them back to my computer case.  Is this possible?

Things to note:
I want the drives to be put into a computer case that can be mounted in my server rack so not using some external enclosure that I can't mount on my server rack.

The main problems I'm not able to figure out is how to power the drives without using a motherboard in the case that houses the drives and how to connect them back to the computer from the separate case.

-----------UPDATE---------------

I apologize for the generic nature of the question.  Let me specify a little more.  I know raid enclosures are typically how this is done but I'm looking for a way to skip using the raid enclosure, because they are ridiculously expensive even for a small one, and use a computer case to hold the drives and a power source inside that case that is completely independent of the actual computer.  Since the drives exist in a completely different enclosure they will still need a way to link back to the computer.  As an example, this case ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00N9CXGSO/?coliid=I2MCMI8S8JZRM7&colid=1XT6Z1YFXQS37&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00N9CXGSO)) filled with hard drives and powered by it's own PSU and connecting back to the computer, using esata ports preferably.  My current setup is JBOD and I have no more room to add additional hard drives in the case but I want to switch it over to a RAID 5 configuration so I need more space to accommodate all the drives that will be needed, at this point it will need 12 drives at a minimum.  Essentially I want a RAID enclosure without having to pay the price tag of a RAID enclosure.  The cheapest one I've found that looks like it might work only holds 4 drives and costs $280 and I need more than 4 drives worth of room.

Major problems are how to power the hard drives without getting a RAID enclosure or a motherboard and how to connect them back to the computer, right now I'm assuming this will be an add-on card with esata ports but I'm open to better ideas if there are any.

Comment: *how to power the drives* From practice. System in one case, HDDs (7) in another. Each case have its own PSU (Hiper 650 и Hiper 1100). Ground lines of both PSUs were connected. This monster works for 4 years without any problems.

Comment: As it stands now, your question is way to broad.  there are solutions that can cost you $100 to $100,000 with the information you provided.  You need to get way more specific in what and how.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your terminology right: What you are looking for is called
"RAID Enclosure".

These enclosures are self-powering, so they get their power from the mains and
not from the computer.

They are usually multi-connectors, so you may choose among USB 3.x, eSATA
and perhaps Firewire.

If you wish the speed of eSATA but your computer/motherboard does not have
that port, you may get an eSATA expansion card that goes in a PCI slot.

These are the terms you need to know when searching for a hardware solution.

Comment: this is why i think its too broad.  is he talking about a raid enclusore, or jbod?  when he says he doesnt want a random enclosure, what does he mean?  Does he not want a cardboard box, or does he want a $20,000 rack mount enclosure?

Comment: @Keltari: I'm sure the answer to the $20,000 rack mount is negative ;) But we in any case cannot give hardware recommendations, so the most we can do is set him straight on terminology. Feel free to improve my answer if you wish.